# Link of 'react-router-dom' not working?

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

This is the code in my root component:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/(:filter)" component={App}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is the code in my Footer component that uses FilterLink component

```
const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:
    {" "}
    <FilterLink filter="all"> 
      All 
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="active">
      Active
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="completed">
      Completed
    </FilterLink>
  </p>
);
```

Now this is the code in my FilterLink that uses Link from 'react-router-dom' that doesn't work

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => (
  <Link 
    to={ filter === 'all' ? '' : filter }
    activeStyle={{
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: 'black'
    }}
  >
  {children}
  </Link>
);
```

I cannot find the bug since it's not throwing any error, but just causes my app to not render anything after I applied this code that uses Link. Help?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it? Can you post a solution please

Comment: for the time being i might just use react-router v3 as a quick get around until I have enough time to read up on react-router v4 --- the issue is v3 vs v4

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. It's because of change of syntax for optional parameters.

Change `/(:filter)` to `/:filter?`

Here is guide for using react-router v4:
https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html#connecting-react-router-with-redux-app

I had even another problem with this example. There was missing `exact` prop in NavLink so if you click on FilterLink "completed" or "active" then you still have active "all".